# convert number to formatted string in python with prefix 0s

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert a number in python into a 3 character string, with prefix 0s. For example:

```
8  = "008"
12 = "012"
6  = "006"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use:

```
format(number, '03')
```

Answer (score 5):

My name is format. [String format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

```
>>> '{:03d}'.format(7)
'007'
```

Comment: Relaying a +1 from The British Superspy himself

Answer (score 1):

There is a build-in `string` method `str.zfill()`, examples:

```
>>> '12'.zfill(5)
'00012'
>>> '-3.14'.zfill(7)
'-003.14'
>>> '3.14159265359'.zfill(5)
'3.14159265359'
```

see: http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html